# How to explain the reasoning for and against a font choice?

Tags: fonts, branding, client-relations

I have a client who runs a fairly traditional transport business; no thrills, creativity or fun about it.

Until recently, he has been using a combination of `Bookman Old Style Bold` for headings with `Comic Sans MS` for main content on all internal and external documentation.

I have tried to explain in a neutral manner (without offending) that his ongoing clients expect a level of professionalism that Comic Sans just does not represent, despite that he has often stuck to his guns.

As the person who makes most of the new documents, I have sort of forced him to change over a long period by simply using Bookman Old Style alone, and avoiding the topic of font when discussing the work. This is not exactly kosher in my opinion, as I'm making a decision for him.

**How can I explain the reasons for using or not using a font, in a clear and concise manner?**

**How do you describe the effect that a font will have? Are there a set of broad categories that you can use to describe fonts (and maybe their personalities)?**

Comment: Seriously? Comic Sans for text not headings? Ouch!

Comment: who needs thrills, creativity or fun when you have comic sans?

Comment: Not easy being a designer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**As a general guideline,** you can't reason someone out of a decision they didn't reason their way into. If Comic Sans gives him the fuzzy-wuzzies because it looks cozy and friendly, you have to point out the emotional impact it has on his clients/vendors. (That is, it makes him look like he's running his shop out of his basement.)

**As far as tactics go, try this:**

Go through the papers on his desk and in his files. Find any examples of similar documentation from any other companies. Also grab copies of *The Wall Street Journal, The New York Times,* etc. whatever publications he might respect.

Ask him if he finds those documents to be serious and professional. Ask him to try to articulate *why.* Ask him if his bank statements come in Bookman etc. or in Comic Sans.

Point out that none of the professional, money-handling, serious businesses use Comic Sans, or any other handwriting font. (At this point I'd get sarcastic and point out that none of them use *crayon* either, but that's just me.)