# Should 'banner logos' be used in web design?

Tags: website-design, logo

So I'm developing a site, and as examples I went to many major companies sites ( Amazon, Ebay, Facebook, Imgur, Pandora, Microsoft, StackOverflow, YamahaMotorsports ), as well as some smaller, but still well known in the industry, websites ( Knapheide Mfg., Linetec, Apogee and a couple others ) The trend seems to be a smaller logo attached to a menu of sorts. I modeled the design after this concept, but received some criticism within the company for not using the 'banner logo' that the old site used. And instead using a smaller logo with some simple styling on the header to give some artistic pop, but still keeping it clean. What are your opinions on this? Was I going in the right direction? Or was I off the mark? ( images for reference )

Banner Logo[image]

Logo and Styling I wanted to use ( with menu built up on top of either of these )

[image]

( but spread across the whole header )

Logo: 
[image]
( but smaller, obviously )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're off the mark but not necessarily for design, though not necessarily NOT for design either.

You're off the mark because you can't seem to justify the reason behind the shift. If you're changing someones branding you should have very sound reason to do so, it doesn't appear you have that. See this question and the answers as possible help on that: [How to explain to a client that their logo is incredibly poor](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27455/how-to-explain-to-a-client-that-their-logo-is-incredibly-poor)

You make no mention of the rational --- no print reasons, no brand identity reasons, no UX/SEO reasons.

The company you work for is not any other company. You don't have make a small logo attached to a menu just because a lot of other companies do it.

Comment: Thanks alot! They are combining 3-ish sites into one site, and I tried to go with a 'modern' look for the header, but they want to keep the header look from an old one, and I think it just makes the page look archaic in comparison to the functionality of the page :/

Comment: @PugsOverDrugs sure thing. Hope it helps. If you're not looking for additional answers here consider marking this one correct. It helps us stay organized and quickly find the Unanswered questions.