# Doing website for a client but logo is not good quality

Tags: website-design, logo, image-quality, canva

I'm doing a website for a client and they provided me the logos but,
the logos all have a white background which I've tried to remove but I cannot.

I use Canva to adjust the logos. The logos are just blurry and not good quality. How can re-adjust these logos to make them sharper and be able to expand them? Do I have to go into the program they originally created their logo on, or can I do this without those resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to explain to a client that their logo is incredibly poor](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27455/how-to-explain-to-a-client-that-their-logo-is-incredibly-poor)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/785/designing-around-an-awful-logo

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, freely. Have you tried to ask your client for a better version of the logos?

Comment: No offense, but I am really worried about someone "designing" a website for a client and not knowing this basic, fundamental, important thing... Besides using "canva" as a tool...

Comment: @Rafael how could that *not* be taken with offence? We are here to help out and also give *constructive* criticism, not chastise their experience (or lack thereof).

Comment: I am worried, for a client and for a designer who makes a project without being prepared about fundamental things using a tool not adequate. That should not be taken as an offense but as a concern. That is why this is a comment, not an answer. I am worried and I have the "obligation" to make it noticed; with some luck the new designer will take notes, to have better capacitation next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Designing around an awful logo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/785/designing-around-an-awful-logo)

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have been given the [raster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) version of the logo.

Tell them you need the [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) version.

> The most common type of vector file type for websites is `.svg`
>
> > Some other common vector file types are `.ai`, `.eps`

> The most common raster file type for websites is `.png`
>
> > Some other common raster file types are `.jpg`, `.tiff`

---

For more information on the difference between Raster and Vector, see [What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/260/63979)

---

<del>If they don't have the option of Vector files, there **are** some options for you, such as cleaning up the image in Photoshop and then tracing (auto or manual - with the *Pen tool*) in Illustrator, although depending on the complexity of the logo, it can be quite annoying.</del>

<sub>**Updated, because this may not necessarily be such a good idea (for legal reasons) will leave at that until I get further input.**</sub>

Comment: You may want to be careful if you go with the retracing route. I would definitely explain your problem to the client and ask them for written permission before doing so, as retracing a logo could potentially be illegal, regardless of the quality of the logo.

Comment: I would doubt that @Emilie. I've lost track of how many poorly supplied logos I've recreated on the fly. The legality of doing so has never even entered my mind. If the client is indeed the company the brand is for, then retracing wouldn't present any legal issues in my opinion. In fact, if you are adept enough at recreating, the client will most likely never even know unless you tell them.

Comment: @Scott - It's a known fact that any logo can be retraced faster than the ten emails it takes to explain to a client what a vector image is ;)

Comment: @mayersdesign I wouldn't say "any" logo, if it's an extremely complex design (which it **shouldn't** be).... it may not be so easy to recreate.

Comment: @mayersdesign ten??? well you must have clients that prefer to keep things brief `:)`.

Comment: @Scott Well retracing an existing (vector) logo can be problematic legally which is what I'm basing my reasoning on. In terms of the law, I doubt whether the image is pixel-based or vector-based makes any difference. I would still get a written permission from the client. This one client doesn't seem particularly in the know, who knows if they even got the rights released in the first place...

Comment: Why would a company *not* have the rights to their *own* brand??

Comment: @Scott If the designers don't specifically waive author rights, they retain the right, and moral rights cannot be waived (at least in Canada that's how it goes). Typically, small businesses are not aware of that and assume that if they paid for the thing, it's theirs.