# How to tell a client their Logo needs reworking?

Tags: website-design, logo, client-relations

I am designing a website for someone who has given me an undigitised logo of them they have not used anywhere yet. I do not know where it came from so need to make sure it isn't just a slightly modified copy of something from the Internet.

The overall problem is that it just is not a good logo and won't really work as such. It is not particularly special or recognizable, it has too much whitespace and weird lines isn't readable and doesn't fit (message wise) with the Image he has been using as a Key Visual or Profile Picture. The colors are also somewhat bad (red, neon green from a text highlighter and pink) and it is too fine and unrecognizable when used small.

I think he either did it himself or his wife might have. Problem is, most of his competitors have bad or no logos and websites. Only some of the very popular/famous people have acceptable to good ones so I don't know if presenting him with some of those will help as was stated in this [How to explain to a client that their logo is incredibly poor](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27455/how-to-explain-to-a-client-that-their-logo-is-incredibly-poor?rq=1) Question?

What can I tell him/do to convince him to let me change it?